# list object was not recognized

Tags: c#, list

I have a problem about my object type. The object i got Caegory. When a the list contains it object must not be added however the code bellow adds it and second time i send the same object it does not add. So i think it is about casting bu even i do casting it worked as i described before. I can solve it with for loops but i want to learn why this is not working.

```
private List<Category> choosenCategoriesList = new List<Category>(); //categoriesList to be used in categorization stage
private List<Category> categoriesList = new List<Category>();

Category categ = categoriesList.Find(x => x.name == cdm_comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
if (!choosenCategoriesList.Contains(((Category)categ)))
{
      choosenCategoriesList.Add(categ);
      categorizationFinished = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you declared an equality comparison method on Category?  i.e. is it IComparable, IEquatable, etc?

Comment: no i will check it now. I thought contains((Category)categ)) does it for me

Comment: `Contains` needs to know how to compare two items so that it can determine that they are equivalent.  If you don't specify anything then it will use the default comparison method as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx, and this must currently be determining that these items are not the same

Comment: the function `contains` calls the `Equal` function of a object. with the IEquatable interface implemented you can decide what makes a object equal to a other object. If you don't you need to exact duplicates aka the same reference of a object for `equal` to return a true.

Comment: @LordWilmore it returns false as == comparison

Comment: @LordWilmore it is coming from another place the values are same but different referencepoints

Comment: Yes, so you need to pass in a comparator that checks for _equivalence_ rather than matching references

Comment: I recommend to use `ISet<Category>` (`HashSet<Catetory`) instead of `List<Category>` for choosen categories. It guarantees the entry of only unique elements.

Comment: MS provide an example in the documentation for the for `Enumerable.Contains`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `List.contains()` you need to implement the `IEquatable` interface and override the `Equals` function for your class.

```
public class Category: IEquatable<Category>
{

   string name;
   int id;

public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        Category objAsCategory = obj as Category;
        if (objAsCategory == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsCategory);
    }

public bool Equals(Category other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.id.Equals(other.id));
    }
}
```

This tells your object what makes it a duplicate when Equals is called based on your description instead of needing to be a exact reference of the object.

A other option is the use `List..Exists((x => x.name == "name");` This works the same a find but will return a Boolean instead of the found object.

more info on this can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because you are getting item in categ as selcted item. second time may be item is not there so its empty and not adding to the list

Comment: but at the beginning there are those items.
eg Environment category is in the choosenCategoriesList
i compare objects in immediate window even thy are identical it returns false. Even if i cast it the result is false